# Plant with purple/white/yellow flower

Tags: species-identification, botany

This plant popped up as a volunteer in a flower box in Winnipeg, Manitoba.

It is roughly 6-inches tall by 6-inches wide.

What is it?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The plant is [*Convolvulus tricolor*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolvulus_tricolor), the dwarf morning-glory. It belongs to the family Convolvulaceae.Blue, white, red and pink flowering cultivars of this plant are available$^1$. It is a annual/perennial growing to 0.3 m (1ft) by 0.2 m (0ft 8in) at a medium rate$^2$.

[image]

[image]

[Image source](https://plantsam.com/convolvulus-tricolor/)

References:

1. [Plantasm](https://plantsam.com/convolvulus-tricolor/)
2. [PFAF database](https://pfaf.org/user/Plant.aspx?LatinName=Convolvulus+tricolor)